# Why do all of the coordinates have the same value?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a snake clone, but whenever I run it, the tail pieces all get assigned the same value as the head. I can't tell why this is happening.

This code is supposed to draw the entire tail, then update each tail piece's coordinates to the ones of the piece before it.

```
for (var i = 1; i < snake.length; i++) {
    snake[i].draw();
    snake[i].x = snake[i-1].x;
    snake[i].y = snake[i-1].y;
}
```

full code: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HaFBpaasoqNTi5tnNLr5O9vIM4oTujgv

Comment: You are programmatically assigning the same value to all coordinates `snake[i].x=snake[i-1].x;
snake[i].y=snake[i-1].y;`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the opposite assignment.

```
snake[i - 1].x = snake[i].x;
snake[i - 1].y = snake[i].y;
```

With your approach you have this

```
...  ...  ...
0.1  0.1  0.1
1.1  0.1  0.1
1.0  1.0  0.1
```

Code

```js
const coor = [
  {x: 0, y: 1},
  {x: 1, y: 1},
  {x: 1, y: 0}
];

for(let i = 1; i < coor.length; i++) {
  coor[i].x = coor[i - 1].x;
  coor[i].y = coor[i - 1].y;
}

console.log(coor);
```

With the given you get this. The last one is the same as there is no more items.

```
...  ...  ...
0.1  1.1  1.1
1.1  1.1  1.0
1.0  1.0  ...
```

Code

```js
const coor = [
  {x: 0, y: 1},
  {x: 1, y: 1},
  {x: 1, y: 0}
];

for(let i = 1; i < coor.length; i++) {
  coor[i - 1].x = coor[i].x;
  coor[i - 1].y = coor[i].y;
}

console.log(coor);
```